# Configure SLF4J to log a custom field when printing exception stack trace?

Tags: java, slf4j

```
class MyException extends RuntimeException {

    private final String myCustomField;

    public MyException(myCustomFIeld) { this.myCustomField = myCustomField; }

    public String getMyCustomField() { return myCustomField; }

    @Override
    public String getMessage() { return null; }
}

public class MainClass {

    private static final Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainClass.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            if (true) { throw new MyException("myCustomField"); }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Exception: ", ex)
        }
    }
}
```

This prints the stack tarce with the given message.

Is it possible to configure the loggers **globally** to also print the custom field of the thrown exception (if `ex` is an instance of `MyException`)?

Comment: Will it be more simple to return `myCustomField` in `getMessage` method of `MyException`?

Comment: @samabcde Unfortunately I can't modify the exception class.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the exception is instance of custom exception using `instanceof`
like

```
if(ex instanceof MyException){
    log.error("Exception: {}, myCustomField :: {} ", new Object[]{ex.getMessage(), ex.getMyCustomField() });
}
```

Comment: I would like to somehow configure the logger so I wouldn't have to rewrite every log statement.